# How to Export ASP.Net Web Page to PDF

Tags: asp.net, pdf

How to Export ASP.Net Web Page to PDF?
I want to export current ASP.Net web page into PDF.

Comment: Do you need to be able to do this with _every_ ASP.NET page on your site, or just _some_ of them?

Answer (score 2):

As asp.net web page get render in HTMl so you can user ITextSharp to convert HTML page into PDF

here is code to Convert HTML to PDF

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter twr = new StreamWriter(mem);
        HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(twr);
        base.Render(myWriter);
        myWriter.Flush();
        myWriter.Dispose();
        StreamReader strmRdr = new StreamReader(mem);
        strmRdr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
        string pageContent = strmRdr.ReadToEnd();
        strmRdr.Dispose();
        mem.Dispose();
        writer.Write(pageContent);
        CreatePDFDocument(pageContent);
    }
    public  void CreatePDFDocument(string strHtml)
    {

        string strFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("test.pdf");
        // step 1: creation of a document-object
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2:
        // we create a writer that listens to the document
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create));
        StringReader se = new StringReader(strHtml);
        HTMLWorker obj = new HTMLWorker(document);
        document.Open();
        obj.Parse(se);
        document.Close();
        ShowPdf(strFileName);

    }
    public void ShowPdf(string strFileName)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(strFileName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: thanks. tried it. but it is giving error " Input string was not in a correct format." at line " obj.Parse(se); "

Comment: iTextSharp appears to have a very restrictive license (AGPL) if you use the free version.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the page in a browser and print it to a PDF using a free tool like CutePDF.

This tool adds a printer that enables you to save the document/web page as a PDF.

http://www.cutepdf.com/

Comment: no i want this is to be done by asp.net program. Like user will click on export button and webpage will get download as PDF.